# Optimise Quesry containing Joins and Sub Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I've inherited an application for a client and have been working on the following query which takes 187 seconds and searches 304M table rows in order to send back 444 result rows.

Am I right to want to get rid of the sub selects and replace them with joins? I can't find a way to do it correctly. Any help optimising this query would be hugely appreciated. Thanks...

```
SELECT Business.name, Business.primary_city, Count(click.id) as clicks, Count(DISTINCT email_leads.parent_message_id) as tot_email_leads, Count(bc.business_id) as county_no, Count(br.business_id) as region_no, count(reveals.id) as reveals_no

FROM businesses as Business

LEFT JOIN business_clickthroughs as click ON ( Business.id = click.business_id  AND (click.created BETWEEN '2014-04-01 00:00:00' and '2014-04-30 23:59:59'))
LEFT JOIN users as U ON Business.id = U.business_id
LEFT JOIN messages as email_leads ON (U.id = email_leads.from_to AND (email_leads.parent_message_id is null OR email_leads.parent_message_id = email_leads.id )  AND (email_leads.created BETWEEN '2014-04-01 00:00:00' and '2014-04-30 23:59:59'))
LEFT JOIN business_counties as bc ON Business.id = bc.business_id                   
LEFT JOIN businesses_business_types as bt ON Business.id = bt.business_id 
LEFT JOIN business_reveals as reveals ON (reveals.business_id = Business.id  AND (reveals.created BETWEEN '2014-04-01 00:00:00' and '2014-04-30 23:59:59'))
LEFT JOIN business_regions as br ON Business.id = br.business_id 

WHERE 1=1 

Group By Business.id;
```

Comment: Is 304m the total number of rows between all the tables? That it brings back 444 rows from the primary table (grouped by what appears to be the primary key) suggests that has only 444 records. Further, how are the tables indexed? How many of the joins are only having one matching row, as most of your counts are counting the non null occurences of ids, when with joins to tables with more than one matching row will result in duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the query you are writing, the subselects are probably the right way to go.  You don't show the actual original query, so this is really just speculation.

Your query is joining data along what could easily be separate dimensions -- users, messages, counties, "reveals" (whatever that is).  The joins would then result in a cartesian product of these dimensions for each business, further magnifying the data and slowing the query down.

And, if your larger tables have 300+ million rows, then 300 seconds to summarize *all* the data in 8 or so tables doesn't seem unreasonable.  Your query doesn't have any `where` conditions that are filtering the data.  The `join`s are all `left join`s, which reducing filtering.

If performance is an issue, then ask *another* question.  Include the actual query, the `explain` plan for the query, and the layouts of the tables (particularly index structures).

Comment: thank you for eplying so quickly. I will post another question now with the information you asked for.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your really quick reply. I think 300M was the number of rows searched (incl. joins and subselects) to generate the results, not the size of the table.
I _think_ my Q is about performance but it's also about 'correctness' the query looks cumbersome and inelegant to me but I'm far from an expert in SQL. BTW the query in the link below is different to the one I posted yesterday, it's the unedited original.

I posted the data you suggested here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312832/how-to-optimise-a-query-containing-joins-and-subqueries)